# Strange redirect and session behaviour

Tags: django, session, redirect, session-variables

I have a registration divided into few steps. Current page is saved in session. But my functions behave weird. If we refresh `step1`, variable in session is changed to `2`, and instead of it `step2` is loaded. Inside this step I'm checking if the user had been already created, and if not reduce `step` to 1 and redirect to the view hoping that `step` will be rendered. But instead I'm getting

```
def my_rte_landing(request):
    step = request.session.get("step", request.REQUEST.get("step", 1))
    logging.debug("my_rte_landing top step: %s" % step)

    if request.method == "POST":
        (... next steps ...)
    else:
        if step == 1:
            logging.debug("step 1")
            html = render_step1(request)
            request.session["step"] = 2      

            return render_to_response('socialauth/login_page.html',{'html': html,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))            
        else:
            logging.debug("step 2")
            logging.debug("step2, step: %s" % request.session.get('step'))
            new_user = True
            new_user_id = request_user_uid(request, request.user.id)    
            html = render_step2(request)
            request.session["step"] = 3

            return render_to_response('socialauth/login_page.html', 
                                    {'html': html}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here's my function checking for existence of user:

```
def request_user_uid(request, user_id):
    if request.session['step'] == 2:
        logging.debug("1 here")
        id = get_user_id(user_id)
        if id:
            logging.debug("2. here")
            return id

        request.session['step'] = 1
        logging.debug("3. here")
        logging.debug("step: %s" % request.session.get('step'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_rte_landing'))
```

And my debug looks like this (I'm visiting page for the first time, not logging, refresh, I can see step2, refresh , still step 2)

```
2010-11-30 17:11:21,434 DEBUG my_rte - nie zalogowany
2010-11-30 17:11:23,245 DEBUG my_rte_landing top step: 1
2010-11-30 17:11:23,246 DEBUG step 1
(first refresh)
2010-11-30 17:11:34,626 DEBUG my_rte_landing top step: 2
2010-11-30 17:11:34,626 DEBUG step 2
2010-11-30 17:11:34,626 DEBUG step2, step: 2
2010-11-30 17:11:34,626 DEBUG 1 here
2010-11-30 17:11:34,628 DEBUG 3. here
2010-11-30 17:11:34,628 DEBUG step: 1
(second refresh)
2010-11-30 17:11:59,523 DEBUG my_rte_landing top step: 3
2010-11-30 17:11:59,523 DEBUG step 2
2010-11-30 17:11:59,524 DEBUG step2, step: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset the step ..

```
        new_user_id = request_user_uid(request, request.user.id) 
        # request.session["step"] is currently set to 1 ... however the 
        #  following lines undo that...
        html = render_step2(request)
        request.session["step"] = 3
```

So while you might set step == 1 in request_user_uid() the very next thing you do is set it back to 3...

Answer (score 0):

you mix return values:

```
def request_user_uid(request, user_id):
    if request.session['step'] == 2:
        logging.debug("1 here")
        id = get_user_id(user_id)
        if id:
            logging.debug("2. here")
            return id #### !!!! returning some value

        request.session['step'] = 1
        logging.debug("3. here")
        logging.debug("step: %s" % request.session.get('step'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_rte_landing')) #### !!!! HttpResponseRedirect
```

and function usage: `new_user_id = request_user_uid(request, request.user.id) # contains HttpResponseRedirect instance`
is it intentional?

Comment: I mean, you don get redirect there, only `HttpResponseRedirect` instance in `new_user_id`